# Font Problem: empty folder "usr/local/texlive/texmf-local" & no TrueType folder!

Tags: fonts, truetype

My goal is to install to TexLive the Font "Barlow.ttf", which is a TrueType Font. I downloaded this font from google fonts:

[image]

After opening usr/local/texlive/texmf-local, I found the folder "fonts", which has no subfolder "TrueType". The weird thing is, even if I go to "type1" or other folders, there is no font to see.

[image]

Then I created a new folder "TrueType" and dropped the folder "Barlow", which includes a lot of .ttf.

[image]

Finally I compiled with TexStudio the following file (with the compiler XeLatex) and get an error:

[image]

Anyone an idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: You have to run texhash, which is "update the filename database" and then use the full filename `\setmainfont{Barlow.ttf}`

Comment: how can I run "texhash"? What is this?

Comment: If you plan on using it with xelatex or lualatex you don't need to install it inside TeXlive or run texhash; just install it like you would install any other font on your system.

Comment: By default xetex will not find fonts in the texlive tree by name such as Barlow you would need the file name. Simpler is to install the font as a system font (as used by your browser, libre office, etc)

Comment: @BilalYilmaz: Which operating system do you have and which TeX distribution?

Comment: I have a MacOS 11.5.1, so I guess I have MacTex. I installed now TeX Live utility. Is this what I need?